# I got Nuxt Internal Server Error when I added dynamic meta tags from server in nuxt 2 vue js and laravel as backend

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vercel, nuxtjs3, production

I got
`Nuxt Internal Server Error`
when I reload or directly go to specific route just in production
in local everything is ok
I just added to asyncData to get dynamically meta tags

I have changed vercel config and nuxt.config.js but I didn`t solve this problem